# Why do all data end up in one partition after reduceByKey?

Tags: apache-spark

I have Spark application which contains the following segment:

```
val repartitioned = rdd.repartition(16)
val filtered: RDD[(MyKey, myData)] = MyUtils.filter(repartitioned, startDate, endDate)
val mapped: RDD[(DateTime, myData)] = filtered.map(kv=(kv._1.processingTime, kv._2))
val reduced: RDD[(DateTime, myData)] = mapped.reduceByKey(_+_)
```

When I run this with some logging this is what I see:

```
repartitioned ======> [List(2536, 2529, 2526, 2520, 2519, 2514, 2512, 2508, 2504, 2501, 2496, 2490, 2551, 2547, 2543, 2537)]
filtered ======> [List(2081, 2063, 2043, 2040, 2063, 2050, 2081, 2076, 2042, 2066, 2032, 2001, 2031, 2101, 2050, 2068)]
mapped ======> [List(2081, 2063, 2043, 2040, 2063, 2050, 2081, 2076, 2042, 2066, 2032, 2001, 2031, 2101, 2050, 2068)]
reduced ======> [List(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 922, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)]
```

My logging is done using these two lines:

```
val sizes: RDD[Int] = rdd.mapPartitions(iter => Array(iter.size).iterator, true)
log.info(s"rdd ======> [${sizes.collect().toList}]")
```

My question is why does my data end up in one partition after the reduceByKey?  After the filter it can be seen that the data is evenly distributed, but the reduceByKey results in data in only one partition.

Comment: I think that the issue may be related to the reaprtitioning which occours after mapping the `filtered` into the `mapped` RDD since you're changing the keys, may you check this?

Comment: I updated the question with the log info for the map step, but the partition sizes are the same.

Comment: How many unique keys do you have after your reduce?

Comment: 922. So the operation is correct. It's the fact that the data is not distributed after the reduce that I am trying to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question, since I figured it out.  My DateTimes were all without seconds and milliseconds since I wanted to group data belonging to the same minute.  The hashCode() for Joda DateTimes which are one minute apart is a constant:

```
scala> val now = DateTime.now
now: org.joda.time.DateTime = 2015-11-23T11:14:17.088Z

scala> now.withSecondOfMinute(0).withMillisOfSecond(0).hashCode - now.minusMinutes(1).withSecondOfMinute(0).withMillisOfSecond(0).hashCode
res42: Int = 60000
```

As can be seen by this example, if the hashCode values are similarly spaced, they can end up in the same partition:

```
scala> val nums = for(i <- 0 to 1000000) yield ((i*20 % 1000), i)
nums: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, Int)] = Vector((0,0), (20,1), (40,2), (60,3), (80,4), (100,5), (120,6), (140,7), (160,8), (180,9), (200,10), (220,11), (240,12), (260,13), (280,14), (300,15), (320,16), (340,17), (360,18), (380,19), (400,20), (420,21), (440,22), (460,23), (480,24), (500,25), (520,26), (540,27), (560,28), (580,29), (600,30), (620,31), (640,32), (660,33), (680,34), (700,35), (720,36), (740,37), (760,38), (780,39), (800,40), (820,41), (840,42), (860,43), (880,44), (900,45), (920,46), (940,47), (960,48), (980,49), (0,50), (20,51), (40,52), (60,53), (80,54), (100,55), (120,56), (140,57), (160,58), (180,59), (200,60), (220,61), (240,62), (260,63), (280,64), (300,65), (320,66), (340,67), (360,68), (380,69), (400,70), (420,71), (440,72), (460,73), (480,74), (500...

scala> val rddNum = sc.parallelize(nums)
rddNum: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:23

scala> val reducedNum = rddNum.reduceByKey(_+_)
reducedNum: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int)] = ShuffledRDD[1] at reduceByKey at <console>:25

scala> reducedNum.mapPartitions(iter => Array(iter.size).iterator, true).collect.toList

res2: List[Int] = List(50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

To distribute my data more evenly across the partitions I created my own custom Partitoiner:

```
class JodaPartitioner(rddNumPartitions: Int) extends Partitioner {
  def numPartitions: Int = rddNumPartitions
  def getPartition(key: Any): Int = {
    key match {
      case dateTime: DateTime =>
        val sum = dateTime.getYear + dateTime.getMonthOfYear +  dateTime.getDayOfMonth + dateTime.getMinuteOfDay  + dateTime.getSecondOfDay
        sum % numPartitions
      case _ => 0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wonder if RangePartitioner would help?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing all your processing times are the same.

Alternatively, their hashCode (from the DateTime class) are the same. Is that a custom class ?

Comment: It's a Joda DateTime. There are 922 distinct dates, and they get grouped that way. That's fine. And I understand that all values for the same date need to be on the same machine at some point, to perform the reduce. But I am surprised that all keys end up in the same partition, the work is not distributed.